# How to exit or quit android application?

Tags: android, exit

I have created an sample application for android and tested it in my htc android mobile.
I want to know how to exit the application?
can anyone give me sample code?
thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exit your current activity by calling the `finish()` method. If you also want to stop services you created you can call `stopService(Intent i)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the finish() method and stop services, clean memoory...

Comment: `Activity` class has methods to override for handling lifecycle events.  There's no guarantee that an overridden `finish()` will get called if the system decides it's time for your activity to close up shop.

Comment: You mean to override onDestroy()?

Comment: That would be one way, but there's no guarantee `onDestroy()` will ever be called.  See the `Activity` docs for an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
System.Exit(0);
```

//Use that to exit the entire application. not just an Activity